# Is this sentence grammatically correct (¿Los gatos negros les parecen mala suerte a ti?)?

Tags: verbos, pronombres, objetos-indirectos

In class, my teacher brought up this question:

¿Los gatos negros _______ _________________ mala suerte a ti?

She said the correct answer was, "¿Los gatos negros **les parecen** mala suerte a ti?" Shouldn't the correct answer be "te parecen" since the object that is receiving the action is "tú" and the subject is "Los gatos negros"? If I am getting something wrong, please let me know. As always, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Are you 100% sure she said that? It seems to me that: parecer mala suerte (which, by the way can be found in pretty decent texts online) would be: parecer [x] a alguien. So, if you have an **a ti**,  the pronoun would be **te**. And if you have a Uds. you get: "les parecen mala suerte a Uds".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Lambie. I was very confused about this.

Comment: Right. It's sure great when the clouds lift. :)

Comment: There is a pronominal usage of _parecer_ so she may have meant that. Why not ask her?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ¿Los gatos negros son de mala suerte? (de por sí)
- ¿Los gatos negros te traen mala suerte? (a ti)
- ¿Los gatos negros les traen mala suerte? (a ustedes)
- ¿Les parece que los gatos negros sean/son de mala suerte? (a ustedes)